# Couple of basic questions about Julia on Windows

Tags: julia

I run Julia on Windows with the `julia.bat` file given in the zip archive. I have a couple of basic questions. This launches a DOS console.

- When typing a `plot()` command Julia returns `plot not defined`. How to use the `plot()` function ? Is there a graphical interface available ?
- When typing `help` I get:

[image]

What does it mean ?

- There is also the `launch-julia-webserver.bat` file in the zip archive. When running this file two DOS windows open but nothing else happens. What can we do with this file and how ?

By the way I do not find any documentation answering such basic questions... of course if you know where to find such a documentation it would be an ideal answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, `help` is implemented as a function, and functions must be called with parentheses. Try `help()`, or to get help for a particular function in the standard library supply it as an argument; i.e., `help(help)`.

When you enter a function name without the parentheses, the default is to print all of the implementations with their argument types.

The main Julia documentation is available online at http://docs.julialang.org/. We also have a mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-dev.

The webserver is pretty rough, especially on Windows. You should be able to open up `http://localhost:2000/` with it running and access a web-based command environment. But you'll probably just want to stick to the normal command line.

Another contributor highlighted the response to `help` as a potential issue for new users and we've opened a bug on it at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1320. It's a new language and there's still plenty of rough edges, so thanks for helping us file those down!

Comment: Thanks. So what do we have to do with the launch-julia-webserver.bat file ?

Answer (score 0):

To use `launch-julia-webserver.bat`, after you double-click it and the two DOS windows open, one of them should say "Connect to `http://localhost:2000/` for the web REPL".  If you open a web browser to `http://localhost:2000/`, you should be greeted with a welcome page that asks for your name and a session name.

Comment: Note that in newer versions of the source, this functionality is automated, so a browser window will pop up automatically.  The binary builds don't include this yet, however, so you still need to open a web browser manually.

Comment: Readers from the future, note the Web REPL will be going away sometime, to be replaced by a new frontend: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1330.